# Special characters such as @, # etc are printed on screen as " (quotes) and £

Tags: keyboard

After installing a trial version of Windows 8, a few of my laptop keys are not working as expected. The problem is like when I try to type <kbd>@</kbd>  by pressing <kbd>Shift + 2</kbd> it shows <kbd>"</kbd> on screen & vice versa.

Similarly -

```
shift + 3      types     £    instead of     #
shift + `      types     ¬    instead of     ~
shift + '      types     @    instead of     "
shift + 2      types     "    instead of     @
```

Answer (score 9):

Your keyboard layout is set to **EN English United Kingdom**.
Change it to **EN English United States**.
The below picture shows the setting in your PC (with Red circle).
[image]
Select the EN English United States (see the tick mark) and it will be back to normal

If you do not see that menu bar in your task bar, you can get it done by the following this picture
[image]

Comment: The original question was for Windows 8, which is significantly different.  The control panel item starts with the word "Clock", and the next button is "Options".

Comment: @Jason Agreed. That skipped my mind